# Removing specific rows from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a data frame e.g.:

```
sub   day
1      1
1      2
1      3
1      4
2      1
2      2
2      3
2      4
3      1
3      2
3      3
3      4
```

and I would like to remove specific rows that can be identified by the combination of sub and day.
For example say I wanted to remove rows where sub='1' and day='2' and sub=3 and day='4'. How could I do this? 
I realise that I could specify the row numbers, but this needs to be applied to a huge dataframe which would be tedious to go through and ID each row.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
DF[ ! ( ( DF$sub ==1 & DF$day==2) | ( DF$sub ==3 & DF$day==4) ) , ]   # note the ! (negation)
```

Or if sub is a factor as suggested by your use of quotes:

```
DF[ ! paste(sub,day,sep="_") %in% c("1_2", "3_4"), ]
```

Could also use subset:

```
subset(DF,  ! paste(sub,day,sep="_") %in% c("1_2", "3_4") )
```

(And I endorse the use of `which` in Dirk's answer when using "[" even though some claim it is not needed.)

Comment: Thats the ticket. Thanks. What does %in% mean?

Comment: It is an example of an infix operator and it returns a logical vector telling you which of the elements in the first argument are contained in the second argument. See ?match where it is defined.

Comment: @BondedDust and here as well

Comment: @42: I don't understand why this is the answer to the question when it does not consider `day` at all.

Comment: @U.Windl I (speaking for BondedDust and myself) agree. Edited.

Answer (score 16):

This boils down to two distinct steps:

1. Figure out when your condition is true, and hence compute a vector of booleans, or, as I prefer, their indices by wrapping it into `which()`
2. Create an updated `data.frame` by excluding the indices from the previous step.

Here is an example:

```
R> set.seed(42)
R> DF <- data.frame(sub=rep(1:4, each=4), day=sample(1:4, 16, replace=TRUE))
R> DF
   sub day
1    1   4
2    1   4
3    1   2
4    1   4
5    2   3
6    2   3
7    2   3
8    2   1
9    3   3
10   3   3
11   3   2
12   3   3
13   4   4
14   4   2
15   4   2
16   4   4
R> ind <- which(with( DF, sub==2 & day==3 ))
R> ind
[1] 5 6 7
R> DF <- DF[ -ind, ]
R> table(DF)
   day
sub 1 2 3 4
  1 0 1 0 3
  2 1 0 0 0
  3 0 1 3 0
  4 0 2 0 2
R>
```

And we see that `sub==2` has only one entry remaining with `day==1`.

*Edit* The compound condition can be done with an 'or' as follows:

```
ind <- which(with( DF, (sub==1 & day==2) | (sub=3 & day=4) ))
```

and here is a new full example

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> DF <- data.frame(sub=rep(1:4, each=5), day=sample(1:4, 20, replace=TRUE))
R> table(DF)
   day
sub 1 2 3 4
  1 1 2 1 1
  2 1 0 2 2
  3 2 1 1 1
  4 0 2 1 2
R> ind <- which(with( DF, (sub==1 & day==2) | (sub==3 & day==4) ))
R> ind
[1]  1  2 15
R> DF <- DF[-ind, ]
R> table(DF)
   day
sub 1 2 3 4
  1 1 0 1 1
  2 1 0 2 2
  3 2 1 1 0
  4 0 2 1 2
R>
```

Comment: ok, I think that will work with a bit of extra help... i need to identify multiple days so I tried your code slightly modified: ind <-which(with(Licor, day=c('1','16','30','37','51','52','57','58'))) but get an error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Work on the expression to compute the indies, you may find `help(match)` useful.

Comment: This answer has an explanation on the strategy needed, how to apply the code, and what code to apply, with examples. This was helpful.

Comment: There seems to be a problem if `ind` is empty: The result is the empty subset instead of the full set (`DF`).

Comment: See also https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17282 for an explanation.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution to your problem using [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)'s `filter` function.

Although you can pass your data frame as the first argument to any dplyr function, I've used its `%>%` operator, which pipes your data frame to one or more dplyr functions (just filter in this case).

Once you are somewhat familiar with dplyr, the [cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) is very handy.

```
> print(df <- data.frame(sub=rep(1:3, each=4), day=1:4))
   sub day
1    1   1
2    1   2
3    1   3
4    1   4
5    2   1
6    2   2
7    2   3
8    2   4
9    3   1
10   3   2
11   3   3
12   3   4
> print(df <- df %>% filter(!((sub==1 & day==2) | (sub==3 & day==4))))
   sub day
1    1   1
2    1   3
3    1   4
4    2   1
5    2   2
6    2   3
7    2   4
8    3   1
9    3   2
10   3   3
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution:

`cond1 <- df$sub == 1 & df$day == 2`

`cond2 <- df$sub == 3 & df$day == 4`

`df <- df[!(cond1 | cond2),]`