# Remove specific rows from a data frame

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [removing specific rows from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112872/removing-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe)

Let's say I have a data frame consisting of a number of rows, like this:

```
X <- data.frame(Variable1=c(11,14,12,15),Variable2=c(2,3,1,4))

Variable1    Variable2
11           2
14           3
12           1
15           4
```

Now, let's say that I want to create a new data frame that is a duplicate of this one, only that I'm removing all rows in which Variable1 has a certain numerical value. Let's say we have these numbers stored in a vector, v.

That is, if v contains the numbers 11 and 12, the new data frame should look like this:

```
Variable1    Variable2
14           3
15           4
```

I've been searching the net for quite some time now trying to figure out how to do something like this. Mainly, I would just need some kind of command saying `removeRow(dataframe, row)` or something like that.

Comment: Have you searched SO for this question?  The answer surely involves using %in% and the extraction operator "[" but I will lay odds its already been answered. For instance the first one that comes up with a search using your question title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112872/removing-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe

Comment: This is a fairly common R practice. Here's a hint, instead of trying to remove the rows you don't want, try to make a new data frame containing the rows that you do want.

Comment: You should post a reproducible example.  `dput` is your friend!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
 X <- data.frame(Variable1=c(11,14,12,15),Variable2=c(2,3,1,4))
> X
  Variable1 Variable2
1        11         2
2        14         3
3        12         1
4        15         4
> X[X$Variable1!=11 & X$Variable1!=12, ]
  Variable1 Variable2
2        14         3
4        15         4
> X[ ! X$Variable1 %in% c(11,12), ]
  Variable1 Variable2
2        14         3
4        15         4
```

You can functionalize this however you like.